# error C2259: 'class' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class, smart-pointers

Now, I understand a good amount about abstract classes at this point, however, I was recently trying to use an abstract class to create a virtual function to receive messages and then another class that has an `std::vector` of smart pointers to this class, but then I got the error C2259. (yes, I did look it up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt206sk.aspx))

Side Note:

I also have recently been reading up a good amount on smart pointers since they are almost (if not always) mentioned in every question relating to pointers.  So I decided to try and implement them for the first time, so my problem might actually be because of my improper use of smart pointers.

Anyways, here is the pure abstract class itself --

```
//Component.h

namespace rpg
{

class Component
{
public:
    virtual void Receive(rpg::Message message) = 0;

    Component();
    virtual ~Component();
};
```

And here is the class that gets the error trying to use the pure abstract class.

```
//ContainerObject.h

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "Component.h"

namespace rpg
{

class ContainerObject
{
private:
    //Create short name for a vector of smart pointers to the pure abstract class
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<rpg::Component>> ComponentList;

    //Create array of Components (std::vector).
    ComponentList myComponents;

public:
    //Send message to all Components in array (std::vector)
    void Send(rpg::Message message)
    {
        if(myComponents.size() > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < myComponents.size(); i++)
            {
                if(myComponents[i] != NULL)
                {
                    myComponents[i]->Receive(message);
                }
            }
        }
    } // end of Send()

    //Add new Component to array (std::vector)
    void AddComponentToMessageList(rpg::Component& component)
    {
        myComponents.push_back(std::make_shared<rpg::Component>(component));
    }

    ContainerObject();
    ~ContainerObject();
};

} //namespace rpg
```

First off, I am trying to practice better code organization (which I am learning some [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html#how-do-components-communicate-with-each-other) <-- also where I got most of this design) and I like the layout if I can keep it.  I also read up some on pure abstract classes [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes) and I saw near the bottom of the page that they still declare a list of pointers to objects of the pure abstract class so I am pretty sure I can use it this way, so why am I getting error C2295 and how can I fix it? Where might I be instantiating it and what causes it to be instantiated?

(I think the term instantiate is probably the part the really confuses me which is why I also asked what causes it, so if you could also include that in your answer it would be much appreciated. (And I did google its definition; I'm still confused))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void AddComponentToMessageList(std::shared_ptr<rpg::Component>& component)
{
    myComponents.push_back(component);
}
```

Try it that way and create the object using std::make_shared before you call AddComponentToMessageList function. I have never tried to instantiate a class with a smart pointer using the copy constructor. From the first sight it looks like it should work, but you never know.

Another note. Prefer interfaces over abstract class. Meaning create an IComponent interface that will look like this:

```
class IComponent
{
public:
    virtual void Receive(rpg::Message message) = 0;
    virtual ~Component() { };
};
```

Then have your classes implement this interface. Obviously your vector needs to change, become a container of std::shared_ptr.

Now I also noticed that you cannot create an abstract class, regardless whether through "new", on the stack, or std::make_shared.

Comment: Strange...Changing the parameter to that allowed it to work perfectly.  Would you happen to know why? (and if so could you elaborate on it?) Also, what is the difference between your `IComponent` class and my `Component` class? I do intend for all later components to inherit my `Component` class.

Comment: Well the difference is that IComponent is an interface. In C++, unlike in C#, there is no interface keyword. So we end up creating an abstract class with no methods implemented. Except the destructor. I am not sure why we are not able to create a class using std::make_shared by passing a copy constructor. It is possible smart pointers do not allow it, even though don't quote me on that, because it doesn't make any sense. Also, if you plan to use smart pointers throughout your code, there is no point in passing the reference of the object itself then wrap it in a smart pointer.

Comment: And that's because, why would you do that? You are going to create the object regardless. If that is the case, then create it using std::make_shared. In your case you are first creating the object, then creating its copy. It is overhead that you do not need.

Comment: As far as other entities in your project are concerned. They can implement IComponent instead of Component. It all depends if you want all your classes deriving from Component have some predefined behavior. If that is the case then an abstract class is the way to go. If that is not the case then you can use interfaces.

Comment: I will do some research on this subject then since I seem to lack knowledge on interfaces.  Also...I had to remove the "&" in `void AddComponentToMessageList(std::shared_ptr<rpg::Component>& component)` in order to actually pass the parameter properly. Otherwise it seems to work properly, the size is increasing and I will continue to do experiments with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: well because you are dealing with pointers, you are not really saving much when you pass std::shared_ptr<..> or std::shared_ptr<..>&. You might be saving a bit of memory, but that's it. Basically without the ampersand you will be making a copy of the smart pointer, but obviously not a copy of the whole object. When you write std::shared_ptr<..>, you don't make a copy of the smart pointer, you rather pass it by its reference.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` should be used when ownership of the object is shared and there is no single responsible entity. `std::unique_ptr` can be usually used for automatic lifetime management otherwise. For interfaces, I prefer to use `struct` rather than `class`, since you get `public` visibility by default. Also, interfaces should make their assignment operator protected (to prevent '*ptr1 = *ptr2') and their destructor either public virtual (as it is here) or protected non-virtual (to prevent 'delete ptr' when 'ptr->Release()' or other should be called.)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to instantiate Component when you call `make_shared` in this line:

```
myComponents.push_back(std::make_shared<rpg::Component>(component));
```

`make_shared` tries to execute `new rpg::Component(component)` which fails because `Component` is abstract.

Comment: What would you recommend I do instead of this line then?

Comment: Do what armanali suggested - change your function to receive the shared_ptr, then whoever calls the function can make the shared pointer on a concrete class (that has `Component` as its base class).

Comment: You need to remove the & in the function parameter definition. Smart pointers of different types can't be passed by reference. Hmm, you seem to have deleted your question. Hopefully you have found this out for yourself.

Comment: I did.  haha.  Thank you.  When I went back to look at the function after I posted my comment I basically face palmed when I saw that. Thanks for the confirmation though that that was indeed the problem.